# Yield-Weed density self starting function (‘DRC.cousens85()’) does nor work properly

Tags: r

I try to fit a Yield-Weed density function on my data (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tBfH-BIM3Vo4Npajx2pLf4q8C7iOnpQH/view?usp=sharing) using the ‘DRC.cousens85()’ self starting function from 'drc' package.
But it does not work properly. 
Any suggestions what can be wrong?
Thanks.

```
> model3 <- drm(y ~ x, fct = DRC.cousens85(), data = my_data)
> plot(model3)
```

The result looks like
!(https://drive.google.com/file/d/170e3plbR_7MoUsdDPFJUBI6XQof3oWti/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the same issue. Actually the function `DRC.cousens85()` is from the `aomisc` package - which won't download from CRAN to newer versions of R.
Downloading `aomisc` from Github worked for me:

```
devtools::install_github("onofriAndreaPG/aomisc")
library(aomisc)
```